# React Clear Form Fields After Submit

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in react that should empty the input fields once the form has been successfully submitted. I am having trouble actually getting this to happen. When I call `setInput({})` the state is cleared but the inputs remain filled

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({});
const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

const handleChange = (e) => setInput({
    ...input,
    [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
});

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setErrors({});

    axios.post(target, input, headers)
        .then( response => {
            setResponse(response.data.success);
            setInput({});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
        });
};
```

Here is a sample of one of the `inputs`

```
            <input 
                name="name" 
                type="text" 
                onChange={ handleChange }
            />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your inputs lack a `value` attribute to control its `value`. Though you have a state your inputs are uncontrolled:

```
        <input 
            name="name" 
            type="text"
            value={input.name}
            onChange={ handleChange }
        />
```

you would also need to initialze your inputs properly:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({name: '', email: ''}); // include all input names
```

and pass the same init object for reset at your form submission:

```
axios.post(target, input, headers)
    .then( response => {
        setResponse(response.data.success);
        setInput({name: '', email: ''});
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the `value` attribute of the input so little wonder nothing clears. But I suggest using [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for that. Here is the idea. Create a reference to that input field so you can manipulate it wherever or whenever you want. So something like this:

```
...
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
const r = useRef(); // <- This is your ref
const handleChange = (e) => setInput({
    ...input,
    [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
});
...
```

Then link it up to the input:

```
           <input 
                name="name" 
                type="text" 
                ref={r}
                onChange={ handleChange }
            />
```

And then clear like so:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      r.current.value = '';
...
...
```